# Router renders components in unexpected order and causes proptype warnings

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Heres my routes:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRedirect to="/Container/1" />    
        <Route path="Container" component={Container}>
            <Route path="1" component={Component1} />
            <Route path="2" component={Component2} />
            <Route path="3" component={Component3} />
            <IndexRedirect to="1" />
        </Route> 
    </Route>
</Router>
```

So the router is responsible for which Component is rendered within `Container`. `Container` will connect to redux and apply the props it gets to it's children using the following function:

```
renderChildren() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children,
        (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
            ...this.props
        })
    );
}
```

In `Component1` I have proptypes defined:

```
Component1.propTypes = {
    prop1: PropTypes.number,
    prop2: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

If I put a `debugger` statement in the render function of `Component1` and `Container`, `Component1` will actually be rendered first, and won't have any props passed to it. This firing a warning saying prop2 is required. After this, `Container` is rendered and then `Component1` again with the props and the warning goes away.

How can I avoid these warnings? Am I breaking a best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Correct Syntax is:

```
Component1.propTypes = {
    prop1: React.PropTypes.number,
    prop2: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

Comment: I guess I didn't include it in the question, but I import PropTypes: `import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';` I'm 100% sure this isn't the cause of the problem.